# getResourceAsStream returns null randomly and infrequently

Tags: java, singleton

I'm getting a null pointer exception when using getResourceAsStream very rarely like once for every 10000 runs. This is how the class looks like

```
public class ConfigLoader{
  private Properties propies;
  private static ConfigLoader cl = null;
  private ConfigLoader(){
        propies = new Properties;
  }
  public static ConfigLoader getInstance(){
    if(cl == null){
          cl = new ConfigLoader();
    }
  }

  public boolean Load(){
   try{
         propies.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));          
   }
   catch(NullPointerException e){
         System.out.println("File Does Not Exist");
         return false;
   }
   return true;
   }
}
```

As can be seen here, the class is implemented as a singleton. The resource clearly exists and is detected most of the time but I'm not sure why its failing once in a while which seems really strange to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It would help to find out what is null (propies? the value returned by getResourceAsStream?)
2. My guess is that you call `getInstance` from several threads and one of them gets a ConfigLoader that has not been properly initialised because your singleton is not thread safe

So I would first confirm with logging that when it fails, it is because `propies` is null, and if it is the case, make the singleton thread safe, for example:

```
private static final ConfigLoader cl = new ConfigLoader;
public static ConfigLoader getInstance() { return cl; }
```

or even better use an enum:

```
public enum ConfigLoader{
  INSTANCE;
  private Properties propies;
  private ConfigLoader(){
    propies = new Properties;
  }

  public static ConfigLoader getInstance(){ return INSTANCE; }

  public boolean Load(){
   try{
         propies.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));          
   }
   catch(NullPointerException e){
         System.out.println("File Does Not Exist");
         return false;
   }
   return true;
   }
}
```

Alternatively, if `getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")` returns null, could it be a packaging issue due to the resource not having been included in your jar?

Comment: Hi, its not a packaging issue as its working 99 percent of the time. I made sure of that. The nulls are happening very sporadically

Comment: @BobLoblaw getResourcesAsStream should not fail randomly for a given jar unless you randomly mess up with class loaders...

Comment: Is there a way to test if one of the threads has a ClassLoader object that's not properly initialized?

Comment: @BobLoblaw what jvm/processor does your (failing) code run on? (not sure about the class loader initialisation to be honest)

Comment: my exact java version is 1.5

Comment: @BobLoblaw does it run on an x86 architecture? If that is the case it is unlikely that this threading issue would occur.

Comment: No, its powerpc. IBM AIX server

Comment: @BobLoblaw Then `propies` being null is a plausible explanation. Do you have a way to reproduce the problem fairly easily (i.e. quickly)? If you do, then it is easy to test. Add a `Properties p = propies;` local variable at the beginning of your load method and check its value when you get a NPE (don't check propies directly as it might become non null by the time the catch block is reached).

Comment: How did you ascertain the unlikeliness of the threading issue if its a x86 arch?

Comment: @BobLoblaw The x86 processors have a fairly strong memory model which prevents some reorderings / caching issues from happening. PowerPcs have a weaker memory model. The jvm also plays a role (hotspot typically does not reorder the publication of a constructor reference before the initialisation of the object's fields). See for example: http://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models

Comment: @BobLoblaw But until you find out what is null, this is only (informed) speculation...